# How can I avoid hidden borders with overlapped button content

Tags: html, css

The program is intended to be used on mobile devices.
Specifying a color for a button causes a couple of pixels of the background color to be visible.
The design intent is to have a clickable button across the full width of the display. The button content will be left justified text, optional right justified text and a right justified image. Most of the buttons can be disabled so I do not want to use s in place of the s.

My understanding is that  contains a `display: inline-block` when its contents are styled with `float`. That causes a 1px border to be added to the top and bottom; it is not visible through Developer Tools.

Is there a style that will suppress the addition of the hidden borders?

HTML file. The `arrow.png` file is 46px x 46px.

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Issue</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="merged_mobile.min.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content_view">
        <div id="home_page" class="page page_1">
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <div class="ul_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Button</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Div</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="nav-side-menu-item" style="background-color: red;">
                            <span>Colored Button</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="nav-side-menu-item" style="background-color: red;">
                            <span>Colored Div</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="nav-side-menu-item" style="background-color: red;">
                            <span>No white space</span><img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>No Arrow</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Extra</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow"/>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

merged_mobile.min.css

```
:root{
--row-height: 67px;
--highlight-color: #077bff;
--tertiary-background-color: #404040;
--primary-font-color: white;
--secondary-font-color: #ccc;
--header-color: #fff;
}

/* Thin */
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Display Thin";
font-display: block;
src: url("../fonts/SF_Pro_Display_Thin.woff2");
}

/* Regular */
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Display Regular";
font-display: block;
src: url("../fonts/SF_Pro_Display_Regular.woff2");
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
min-width: 300px;
}

body{
font-family: 'SF Display Regular', sans-serif;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: white;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
caret-color: orange;
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
user-select: none;
}

p {
margin: 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
outline-style: none;
}

li {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.ul_wrapper li {
background-color: purple;
border-bottom: 1px white solid;
}

button {
height: 36px;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 200;


}
button:focus {
outline-style: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
background-color: #404040;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
background: dimgray;
}

.content_view {
background-color: yellow;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: brown;
}

.nav-side-menu-item {
color: var(--primary-font-color);
font-size: 20px;
height: var(--row-height);
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}

.nav-side-menu-item span:first-child{
float: left;
height: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
width: calc(100% - 150px);
text-align: left;
margin-left: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
line-height: var(--row-height);
vertical-align: baseline;
}

.nav-side-menu-item:disabled, .nav-side-menu-item:disabled span:first-child {
color: lightslategray;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.nav-side-menu-item span:nth-child(2), .nav-side-menu-item span:nth-child(3) {
font-size: 14px;
padding-right: 10px;
float:right;
width: 90px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: transparent;
text-align: right;
height: var(--row-height);
line-height: var(--row-height);
vertical-align: baseline;
}
.nav-side-menu-item img{
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
float: right;
margin-top: 22px;
padding-right: 10px;
opacity: 80%;
}

.page {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

.page_1 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: orange;
}

.ul_wrapper {
height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
height: calc(100% - 50px);
display: block;
overflow: auto;
background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float`(s) [are] having a cascading effect on the spacing within the `li`; such that the whitespace — which one normally doesn't ever see — is taking up space in the layout.

The short answer here is to add `line-height: 0;` to the `li` rule(s). This will cause the *shouldn't-be-visible-in-the-layout-but-is-because-`float`* whitespace to take up 0px vertically, allowing it (the `li`) to collapse around the height of the `button`(s).

An alternate approach would be to rewrite the `button` rules to not rely on `float`… this might be an ideal candidate for a **flex box** solution.

Comment: That helps but it caused problems with `<li class="divider">Section</li>`. No height was allocated for the text. I have found a solution to that problem.